# How many times does the same ROUND and/or SUM execute if used in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

**DB - SQL Server 201x**

The code section below is an altered extraction from a test tool

My question is: how smart is the run-time in executing the same **ROUND(SUM(...)) sections**

Does it execute the first occurrence and use the outcome for the consequent occurrences or does it execute it multiple times.

Is there a smarter way of doing this in SQL Server

```
select
    person.Name 'Name',
    account.AccountCode 'Account Code',
    ROUND(SUM(account.basevalue + account.accuredInteres), 2)    'Account Total'
    case 
        when ROUND(SUM(account.basevalue + account.accuredInteres), 2) =  ROUND(CAST(audit_data.total as decimal(21,6)), 2) then 'MATCH'
        when 
            ROUND(SUM(account.basevalue + account.accuredInteres), 2)  <= ROUND(CAST(audit_data.total as decimal(21,6)), 2) * 1.01 AND
            ROUND(SUM(faccount.basevalue + account.accuredInteres), 2)  >= ROUND(CAST(audit_data.total as decimal(21,6)), 2) * 0.99
            then 'IN TOLERENCE'
        else 'NOT MATCHING' END 'Values Equal ?'
from
    ----
    ----
where 
    ----
```

Comment: Check your execution plan to see what happens. You can always calculate such a value in a sub-query first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the execution plan.  In this case, I would expect `round()` to be executed 7 times for each row in the result set.  However, normally in an aggregation query, the result set is much smaller than the initial data, so this probably adds little overhead to the query.

The `sum()` is a different matter.  It doesn't really matter how many times it is executed.  The expensive part of the operation is the aggregation, typically much more so than individual aggregation functions.

I'm not sure if SQL Server optimizes the multiple `sum()`s or not but I doubt it has much effect on performance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is to get the calculated field ROUND(SUM(account.basevalue + account.accuredInteres), 2) as plain field and then do all comparisons at an external sql select but this is not a better for all cases approach and may be unsuitable for your complete statement. You can however try it on a large data set to see plans and execution times. i believe the extra cost will be minimal.